# Offline app for creating video highlights (photo slideshow and music)

Tags: windows, video, offline, photography, slideshow

There are plenty of mobile applications that allow to pick *the most important* images out of an album and create a short video with fancy background music and transitions (HTC Zoe for example).

Facebook and Google+ also make similar movies at the end of a year to "sum up your past year".

I'm looking for an application for windows that can do similar things with photos from a disk. The only services I have found are online (i.e. [animoto](https://animoto.com/) or [photoshow](http://www.photoshow.com/home/start)).

It would be great if an app would suggest initial automatically generated video with ability to enhance it a litte (add texts, change trantistions or some photos).